# Send Email multiple attachments from LINQ list

Tags: c#, linq, email, outlook-2010

This might be very simple for you Gurus but I'm stumped on this.  I have a method that will gather all the info for an email and then send it out via outlook.  However, I want to account for multiple attachments.  How would I do that?  What do I need to change in my method header?

```
public static void sendOutlookMail(string toAddress, string emailSubject, string ccAddress = null, string emailAttachment = null, string emailBody = null)
```

I know that I have to change, but not sure to what and keep a default value:

```
string emailAttachment = null
```

Thanks in advance.

Please let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass list of string you can replace this:

```
     string emailAttachment = null
```

with this:

```
    List<string> emailAttachment = null
```

Answer (score 1):

ideally you should change that to

```
List<System.Web.Mail.MailAttachment>
```

Hope that helps